# Prove or disprove if $x_k$ is unbounded and $|P|\geq 0$, then either $\lim_{k\to\infty}x_k^{\rm T}Px_k=0$ or $x_k^{\rm T}Px_k$ is unbounded

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, limits

Prove or disprove by counterexample:

For all $k\in\mathbb{N}$, let $x_k\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$, and assume $x_k$ is an unbounded sequence. Let $P$ be symmetric positive semidefinite. Then, either $\lim_{k\to\infty}x_k^{\rm T}Px_k=0$ or $x_k^{\rm T}Px_k$ is unbounded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $P \neq 0$ and $\ker P$ is not trivial. Choose $x_0$ such that $x_0^TPx_0 = 1$ and a non zero $v \in \ker P$. Then
$x_k=x_0+kv$ is unbounded but $x_k^T P x_k = 1$ for all $k$.

Comment: Thanks. $nv$ should be $kv$?

Comment: @krms It wont matter. Since $v \in \ker P$, $Pv = 0$.

Comment: @user458276 Right, but the question requires unbounded $x_k$.

Comment: The sequence is unbounded.

Comment: $v$ is a non zero vector.